# keyboard short cut for accessing previous statements in python IDLE using a Mac

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, python-idle

Is there a keyboard short cut for accessing previous statements in python IDLE? I am using a Mac

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

On Windows this hotkey is alt-p.

However, assuming IDLE has options in Mac ;) you should be able to find out by going to Options->Configure IDLE. Then look in the Keys tab and under Custom Key Bindings, look for "history-previous".

That should tell you what you need to know.

Comment: Thank you! It's Control-p for the Mac

Comment: @Lana, no worries. Though, if you like my answer please accept it =~)

Comment: Alt+P and Alt+N on Windows. Ctrl+P and Ctrl+N on a mac.

Comment: On my mac, the Python/Preferences/keys/Keys Set/ were set for 'IDLE Classic Windows' and C-p initiated a print.  Setting it to 'IDLE Classic Mac' made the C-p do a previous line as described.  This dialog box also lists the key bindings for the various selected settings.

Answer (score 3):

Using IDLE on the MAC you would need <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (not command) for Previous statement (instruction) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> for Next statement.

I was struggling with this same question as I am always using the Up arrow on most of the "shell" style programs.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can scroll back up to any previous line and hit 'return', which will place that statement in the current working line.